# Always Parse JSON as Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

How do I make sure that the `json` variable is always an array? In my code, sometimes `str` is an array and sometimes it isn't. Is there a way to make sure that it's always an array?

```
// array
const str = '[{ "key": "value" }]';
const json = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(json);
// [{
//   key: 'value'
// }]

// json
const str = '{ "key": "value" }';
const json = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(json);

// {
//   key: 'value'
// }

// What I want to happen somehow
const str = '{ "key": "value" }';
const json = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(json);

// [{
//   key: 'value'
// }]
```

I could check the type of `json` using `instanceof`, but I was hoping there would be a fancy ES6 way (with spread?) happen without it giving me an array of arrays with str is wrapped in brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) which will either merge or wrap the parsed JSON.

```js
const jsonObject = '{ "key": "value" }';
const result1 = [].concat(JSON.parse(jsonObject));
console.log(result1);

const jsonArray = '[{ "key": "value" }]';
const result2 = [].concat(JSON.parse(jsonArray));
console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make into an array then flatmap it, if the original json was an array the internal array will get removed.

```js
const str1 = '[{ "key": "value" }]';
const json1 = [JSON.parse(str1)].flatMap(x => x);
console.log(json1);

const str2 = '{ "key": "value" }';
const json2 = [JSON.parse(str2)].flatMap(x => x);
console.log(json2);
```